# How to display nested json value?

Tags: vue.js

I need to display value for month april. Code:

```
{{my_dates['2018-04-23']}}
```

displays:

```
{
   "april":0,
   "may":0,
   "june":0,
   "july":0,
   "august":0,
   "september":0,
   "october":0,
   "income_trips":"0.00",
   "med_services":"0.00",
   "food_services":"0.00",
   "accom_services":"0.00",
   "collegium":"0.00",
   "parking":"0.00",
   "wash":"0.00",
   "other":"0.00",
   "balance":"0.00",
   "employees":0,
   "season_employees":0,
   "complaints":0,
   "reviews":0
}
```

I tried:

```
 {{my_dates['2018-04-23']['april']}}
```

it's display `0`, but I am getting error:

`[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'april' of undefined"`

The follow json should be in my `my_dates` http://vpaste.net/3A0Th

Code of app:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    my_dates: {},
  },

    methods: 
    {
        getTableData: function()
        {
              // GET /someUrl
          this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/ponizovka_get_data').then(response => {
            // get body data
            this.my_dates = response.body;

          }, response => {
            // error callback
          });
        }
    },

    created: function(){
        this.getTableData()
    }

})
```

Comment: did you add v-if directive to check the property?

Comment: very strange. could you please log `my_dates['2018-04-23']` value to the console?

Comment: Objects are not reactive, so arrays  / values are to be used while displaying. Use computed and bind it to a value.

Comment: @SergiiVorobei `console.log('my_dates 2018-04-23 ', this.my_dates['2018-04-23']['april'])` print `my_dates 2018-04-23  42`

Comment: @PrajvalM could you show the code? How to do it?

Comment: are you getting data fro an API as per @Ankit Kumar Ojhas answer\

Comment: I added code of app.js that fetch data to question text.

Answer (score 3):

```
{{ my_dates['2018-04-23']['april'] }}
```

You're right. This is the correct way to access this property, but the error could be related to this value been display before assignment or async operation. You can fix by checking on v-if, using short-circuit, using a computed property (@EmileBergeron suggestion) or even a method.

Fix by checking on `v-if`

```
<div v-if="my_dates && my_dates['2018-04-23']">
  {{ my_dates['2018-04-23']['april'] }}
</div>
```

Fix using short-circuit

```
{{ my_dates && my_dates['2018-04-23'] && my_dates['2018-04-23']['april'] }}
```

Fix with a computed property (@EmileBergeron suggestion)

```
<span>{{ april }}</span>

computed: {
  april () {
    if (!this.my_dates || !this.my_dates['2018-04-23'])
      return null;
    return this.my_dates['2018-04-23']['april'];
  }
}
```

Fix using a method

```
{{ getMyDate('2018-04-23', 'april') }}

methods: {
  getMyDate (date, month) {
    if (!this.my_dates || !this.my_dates[date])
      return null;
    return this.my_dates[date][month];
  }
}
```

There are other approaches like optional-chaining purpose or idx.

- https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining
- https://github.com/facebookincubator/idx

Comment: is it's possible to do it without `v-if`?

Comment: @DmitryBubnenkov a computed would be cleaner in this case.

Comment: @EmileBergeron was right, a computed would be cleaner. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is because, may be you are getting the data from an async source(fetching from API or something). Unless that data is available vue would try to find `my_dates['2018-04-23']` which will be `undefined` so you are getting that error.

Wait until you have fetched you data and then display it.

You can use `v-if` for that:

```
<div v-if="my_dates">{{my_dates['2018-04-23']['april']}}</div>
```

You might still get that error, even after using v-if, so try using computed for getting the values after that.

I hope it helps.

Comment: is it's possible to do it without `v-if` ?